# Selección mediante ruleta en un algoritmo genético

Tags: python-3.x, algoritmos, optimización

Estoy tratando de escribir el código de una ruleta para un algorítmo genético.Supongamos que tenemos 20 número aleatorios del intervalo (0,1). Tenemos también las 20 probabilidades acumuladas relativas a cada uno de los individuos de la población(que consta de 20 individuos).

Sea `G2 = [r1,...,r20]` la lista de números aleatorios. Sea `F3 = [q1,...,q20]` las probabilidades acumuladas(también son números entre 0 y 1).
Supongamos que si comparamos las listas resulta que `q4<r1<q11`, entonces se elige a mayor, es decir, `q11`. análogamente para `r2`, supongamos que tenemos `q3<r2<q9`, entonces se elige a `q9`, y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a `r20`.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
def selec_ruleta(l):
    for i in range(0, 20):
        while F3[i]<G2[l]:
            if G2[l] < F3[i]:
                i += 1
            break
    return F3[i]
```

Luego hago una compresión de listas que sería lo equivalente a girar la ruleta 20 veces

```
LM = [selec_ruleta(l) for l in range(0, 19)]
```

Después la imprimo

```
indx_rul = [print("Indices de la ruleta: {}".format(LM[i])) for i in range(len(LM))]
print(indx_rul)
```

El resultado es 20 veces esto: Indices de la ruleta: (19, 1.0).

¿Qué es lo que falla?
¿Cuál sería el código que haga que la ruleta funcione?

Answer (score 2):

Veo muchas cosas raras en tu código, razón por la cual no acabo de entender qué pretendes. En todo caso te indico las cosas raras que veo, por si te dan la pista para resolverlo.

- Dentro del `while` tienes un `if` cuya condición, si no me equivoco, es la contraria a la que figura en el `while`. Por tanto, si la condición del `while` era cierta, la del `if`  será falsa, por lo que el `i+=1` nunca se ejecutará.
- Justo después de ese `if` tienes un `break`, y ya que no depende de ninguna condición, se ejecutará. Esto causa la terminación del bucle `while`, el cual por tanto se ejecuta una sola vez.
- Quizás esperabas que ese `break` te sacara del `for`, pero no es así. Un  `break` te saca del bucle que se esté ejecutando, que en este caso es el `while`. El `for` por tanto se ejecuta hasta el final (20 veces) lo que puede explicar el resultado observado.
- En la construcción de la lista `LM` mediante comprensión de listas ¿no deberías estar usando `range(0,20)` en lugar de `range(0,19)`? (gracias a @AdriánSanzWallace por verlo y señalarlo en un comentario)
- Dices que te imprime como resultado `(19, 1.0)`, pero no veo de dónde puede salir esa tupla, ya que tal como tienes el código, lo que retorna tu ruleta es un flotante y no una tupla. Entiendo que, o bien el resultado que ves es simplemente `1.0`, o bien el código que has puesto en la pregunta no es el mismo que estás probando tú.
- Usas una *comprensión de listas* para imprimir sus elementos. Eso no debe hacerse, es un antipatrón. Lo que debes hacer es un bucle "normal", como en:

  ```
  for indices in LM:
      print("Indices de la ruleta: {}".format(indices))
  ```

  ¿Por qué es un antipatrón usar una comprensión de listas para esto? Porque las comprensiones se usan para crear otras listas, con los resultados de evaluar mediante alguna "fórmula" los elementos de otra lista. En tu caso la "fórmula" es `print()`, que en realidad retorna siempre `None`, por lo que al final estás creando (innecesariamente) una lista llena de `None`s.
- Finalmente imprimes `indx_rul`. Según lo dicho debería salirte ahí una lista llena de `None`. Me extraña que no lo hayas mencionado.

### Actualización

Creo entender que la misión de la función ruleta es devolver el mayor elemento de `F3` que esté por debajo de `G2[l]` ¿es correcto? Y que podemos asumir además que en `F3` los elementos están ordenados ¿sí? En ese caso creo que podría ser tan sencillo como:

```
def selec_ruleta(l):
  for i in range(20):
     if F3[i] > G2[l]:
        # Si esto se cumple, ya nos hemos "pasado". Abortar bucle
        break
  # El anterior es el buscado
  return F3[i-1]
```

Comment: Iba a escribir más o menos lo mismo, pero veo que ya lo has hecho. Solo añadir que si las dos listas tienen 20 elementos, la F3 la recorre entera mientras que en G2 se deja el último elemento sin pasarselo a selec_ruleta(l) (por si quieres añadirlo)

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Ah, pues también, sí. Edito la respuesta y añado ese detalle

Comment: La lógica de la ruleta en algoritmos genéticos es seleccionar mejores individuos. Para ello insertas un par de nuevos individuos en la lista (se asume lista circular) en cada generación y giras la ruleta. Eso produce una nueva lista a evaluar con varios de los individuos de la generación anterior pero en otra posición, es decir, tienes que copiar CASI TODA la lista en otra pero recorrida 1 o 2 lugares y solo cambian los individuos menos aptos por los propuestos en la nueva generación.

Comment: @abrahamhs Gracias por la aclaración. Creo que tu comentario estaría mejor como comentario a la pregunta, para que el usuario lo pueda ver mejor. A fin de cuentas yo me he limitado a señalar errores lógicos en su código, a partir de su descripción de lo que quería hacer, pero desconociendo lo que _en verdad_ debería hacerse.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que hice fue dividir en intervalos usando como extremos de estos las probabilidades acumuladas que se encuentran en la lista Q, esto es, [0,q1,], [q1,q2], [q3,q4] y así sucesivamente hasta terminar la lista que contiene veinte elementos. Aquí el código que hace lo antes mencionado

```
def QPorIntervalos(J):
    Q = np.cumsum([0] + J)
    Q = list(Q)
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(Q) - 2):
        temp.append([Q[i], Q[i + 1]])
    Q = list(temp)
    # print("El vlaor de Q",Q)
    Q[-1][1] = 1.0
    return Q
```

Con esta idea ahora es más fácil identificar en entre qué probabilidades de la lista Q se encuentran los 20 números aleatorios que genero y guardo en G1. Una vez que se sabe en qué intervalo cae el número aleatorio simplemente se selecciona el supremo de dicho intervalo(extremo derecho). He aquí el código

```
# Lista de valores de ruleta
def ruleta(poblacion, Q, G1):
    new_population_prima = []
    for ri in G1:
        indice = 0
        # verificador=False
        for intervalo in Q:
            if ri > intervalo[0] and ri < intervalo[1]:
                # verificador=True
                new_population_prima.append(poblacion[indice + 1])
            indice += 1
        # if verificador==False:
        #    new_population_prima.append(new_population[1])
    return new_population_prima
```